# Int to Double casting issue

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

I'm an Objective-C developer with little C/C++ experience (and zero training), and I encountered something strange today with hard coded numeric values.

I'm sure it's a simple/stupid question, but can someone please explain why this works:

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  NSLog(@"seconds: %f", [start timeIntervalSinceNow]);
});
// output: seconds: -1.0001
```

And this also works (note number of seconds has changed):

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  NSLog(@"seconds: %f", [start timeIntervalSinceNow]);
});
// output: seconds: -2.0001
```

But this is executed immediately:

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 4 * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  NSLog(@"seconds: %f", [start timeIntervalSinceNow]);
});
// output: seconds: -0.0001
```

However, using `4.0` instead of `4` fixes it:

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 4.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  NSLog(@"seconds: %f", [start timeIntervalSinceNow]);
});
// output: seconds: -4.0001
```

Why do 1 and 2 properly cast to the relevant double value, but bigger numbers (I tested 3 and 4) appear to be represented as `0`?

I'm compiling with Xcode 4.2, configured to use LLVM 3.0.

EDIT:

dispatch_time_t is defined as:

```
typedef uint64_t dispatch_time_t;
```

And dispatch_time is:

```
dispatch_time_t dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t when, int64_t delta);
```

And NSEC_PER_SEC is:

```
#define NSEC_PER_SEC    1000000000  /* nanoseconds per second */
```

Comment: What is dispatch_time's parameter?

Comment: that seems very strange that 1,2 work and 3,4 don't... I would double check that, but you do certainly see instances where ints will evaluate to 0f.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are 1,000,000,000 nanoseconds in a second, so I'm going to assume that `NSEC_PER_SEC` is defined as `1000000000`.

- `4` is of type `int`
- `4.0` is of type `double`

Now assuming that an `int` contains 32 bits, the range of an `int` would be `[-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647]`

`4000000000 > 2147483647`, therefore you'll cause the `int` to overflow, which is causing the value to be set to 0.

**EDIT:** I probably could've worded the above statement better. The overflow could cause the `int` (assuming it's 32 bits in size, as stated above) to equal the value `-294967296`, and `dispatch_time` would be treating any value `<= 0` as 0 seconds. That's where the "0" above came from.

A `double` variable can hold larger values than an `int`, and is able to store an approximation of the value `4000000000`.

Comment: When the calculation overflows, you'll get wrap around, not zero. The value here will probably be < 0, and dispatch is probably treating that as 'do it immediately'.

Comment: @JonHess: I intended it to mean that the overflow is causing the timer to be set to 0, I should probably reword it.

Comment: @JonHess: And I think "overflow" is a better expression than "wrap around", since negative values have a greater unsigned value than positive ones (in terms of the bit sequence and 4000000000 fits into an unsigned 32 bit integer). "wrap around" would kind of imply that bits are chopped off/wrap around past 0000...

Comment: A signed overflow is undefined behaviour in the C standard. In practice, compiler writers may settle on a predictable behaviour, so it's more useful to call it unportable. Using `double` in this case is not appropriate anyhow, since `dispatch_time` expects and `int64_t` for its second argument. The man pages for `dispatch_time` have the following suggestion: "When in doubt, use `ull` as a suffix."

Answer (score 7):

The first two work because 1 * 10^9 and 2 * 10^9 fit in a signed 32-bit int. However, 4*10^9 will not fit in a signed 32-bit int.

4.0 * 10^9 works because floating point can represent that value.

I expect that this will work too:

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, ((int64_t)4) * NSEC_PER_SEC);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about Objective C, but my guess is that 4 * NSEC_PER_SEC is too big for a 32-bit integer.  By using 4.0 you force the the multiplication into floating point arithmetic and get around the problem.

**Update**

It may be 64-bit code, but in some languages (and I know C# is one) a numeric literal defaults to a 32-bit signed integer unless you explicitly define it otherwise.  That may be what's happening here.

Comment: Thanks, "NSEC" is nanoseconds, so it's a big number. I have updated my question with it's definition. By the way, this is all 64 bit code, though I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, on 32-bit UNIX or 64-bit UNIX, int is 32-bits

Comment: I'm not sure about literals, but `int` is certainly 32 bit at least in the current version of Objective-C. Based on @AusCBloke's answer 2 seconds would only just fit in a 32 bit int, so that must be what's going on. Apple recently started pushing everyone to use a new `NSInteger` type, which is 64 bit when compiling for a 64 bit CPU (otherwise it's 32 bit). I imagine they'll switch literals to that type one day.